# Deshabilitar un botón durante 3 segundos

Tags: javascript

Quisiera realizar las siguientes operaciones sobre un `botón` (Enviar):

- Se deshabilitará durante 3 segundos y su texto cambiará a
  "Enviando...".
- Después de los 3 segundos, volverá a tener el texto    "Enviar".

**Código HTML del botón:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar" name="btnEnviar"/>
```

**Código JS:**

```
function confirmEnviar(){
    var pregunta = confirm("¿Deseas enviar el formulario?");
    if(pregunta == true)
        deshabilitar_btnEnviar();
    else
        //No hacer nada.
        event.preventDefault();
}

function deshabilitar_btnEnviar(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("enviar").innerHTML="Enviando...";
    }, 3000);
    document.getElementById("enviar").innerHTML = "Enviar";
}
```

Comment: cuál es la intención de tu código

Comment: Realizar lo que pone en la descripcion entre los comentarios //

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que no te funciona? Piensa que sin el código HTML no sabemos si estás haciendo bien el trabajo de agregar el evento y sin saber si estás ejecutando en algún momento `deshabilitar_btnEnviar()` tampoco. Por favor, proporciónanos un marco de trabajo completo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya actualicé la pregunta con más documentación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He intentado reproducir tu problema, y por lo pronto estás bloqueando y desbloqueando en orden incorrecto, aunque también podría ser debido a que no estás llamando a la función adecuada.

A la hora de confirmar el formulario, primero habría que bloquear el botón y cambiar el texto y, por último, retrasar la ejecución de desbloquear y restaurar el texto del botón los tres segundos.

Un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer podría ser:

```js
function confirmEnviar() {
  miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = true; 
  miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Enviando...";
  setTimeout(function(){
    miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = false;
    miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Enviar";
  }, 3000);
  return false;
}

miformulario.btnEnviar.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    return confirmEnviar();
}, false);
```

```html
<form name="miformulario">
  <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("enviar").innerHTML="Enviando...";
    }, 3000);
    document.getElementById("enviar").innerHTML = "Enviar";
    }
```

Te recomiendo usar `innerHTML` dado que cambia el valor del botón, si lo que quieres

Comment: Los elementos `<input>` no muestran el contenido de `innerHTML`. Son etiquetas de elementos vacíos ([ver documentación](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags)).